# Windows 7, 2 mice, 1 user, and "Switch primary and secondary buttons" on 1 mouse only?

Tags: windows-7, mouse, control-panel

In an effort to reduce the likelihood that I'll get mouse-related RSI in my (dominant) right hand, I've taken to using an additional second mouse with my left.

I'd like to flip the left and right mouse buttons on *just* the left-hand mouse, but the **Switch primary and secondary buttons** option in the Mouse Properties window in Windows 7 applies to both mice.

Does anyone know of a way of achieving what I'm after?

Comment: What are the mice?  (I ask because it's possible the proprietary manufacturer's configuration apps will let you do this - I believe Logitech does, at least.)

Comment: sounds like a way to get shoulder pain instead ;-/ try a trackball if you haven't already, ideally in the middle of a split keyboard. The keyboard width helps the shoulders, the trackball helps the fingers (click with thumb on mine) and putting it in middle helps the wrists. my 2 cents.

Comment: Are you good with a soldering iron? I've only done this once, but on that mouse's board the circuit traces connecting the buttons were big, easy to cut, and easy to solder to. Four cuts and four pieces of wire, plus 30 minutes of your time, might solve your problem. (Of course this voids all warranties and risks destroying the mouse!)

Comment: I have done this with 2 Logitech G9 mice via their software Setpoint. The mice appear as two profile and on one i clicked the option "swap buttons". However, it swapped the buttons for both! So it failed.

Comment: @Shinrai They are just common-or-garden Microsoft "Wheel Mouse Optical".

Comment: @Sirex I have persisted with a trackball, but despise it. Have a split keyboard (check!), and now attempt to stay on the keyboard as much as possible by switching to applications such as Vim and Firefox's Vimperator.However, I still like the option of being able to use the left mouse, but I want to instinctively flip the buttons on the left (which means using it is requires conscious effort).

Comment: @Chris You know, that's no a bad idea! :)  If all else fails, I might give that a shot. Thanks for causing me to re-think the problem!

Comment: @Valamas Ah, shame! :(

Answer (score 5):

The following program worked for me, try it out, hope will be helpful for you! Best of luck!

[EitherMouse 0.4](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic48238.html) - auto switch mouse buttons on second mouse

Comment: +1 This program looks like the perfect solution to the askers problem. Also, welcome to Stack Exchange!

Answer (score 3):

Unless your mouse has some proprietary drivers/apps that let you reconfigure the buttons to whatever you want, you can't do it from Windows alone. As you already found, the Windows Mouse properties window applies to all plugged-in and recognized pointing devices. Collectively they will share one cursor and set of behaviors (double-click speed, appearance, primary/secondary, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Try EitherMouse. Using it I've configured per mouse settings, at least swap buttons for left mouse.

http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/44468-eithermouse-0581-not-just-for-leftys-anymore/

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar set-up with two mice and a track-ball - all from Logitech.

Using the SetPoint software from Logitech you can configure every Logitech mouse/trackball individually, even the "swap mouse buttons" function (just tested on Windows 7 and SetPoint v6.51.8).

Unfortunately this is a manufacturer dependent solution and you did not write what mice you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If one of the mice is microsoft, you can use microsoft intellipoint to swap buttons on only the microsoft mouse. I have a logitech and a MS mouse on a win 7 64 bit machine. Don't use the newer MS mouse and keyboard center, it will swap buttons for all mice. I had to uninstall that and get the older intellipoint software. Logitech's setpoint was not letting me do what I wanted to.

Answer (score -1):

I've been using two mice for a few years now, and the simplest solution, has been to learn to use the buttons in their default layout.  Part of the reason for this is to maintain compatibility on any machine I'm assigned.  Regardless of the workstation I'm on, I can always just throw in a second USB mouse, and start using them both.